# What is wrong with my Neo4j query for Py2neo?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

This is my query for Py2neo for Neo4j database

```
MATCH (u:User),(p:Prize),(ca:Category) CREATE (ch:Challenge {chid:'dassdshhhhasdasda',challenge_title:'Exm 2015', total_question_per_user:200,challenge_status:1,timestamp:'1471516538.4643',date:'2016-08-18'}), (p)-[:BELONG {rank:3}]->(ch),(ca)-[:BELONG {percentage_question:20}]->(ch) WHERE u.username = 'xyz@gmail.com' AND p.pid = 'e766d8cd-26d1-4848-ac97-15c233caa4d4' AND ca.catname = 'nature'
```

But when I run it manually in Neo4j database command line then it show error

```
Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I' (line 1, column 287 (offset: 286))
"MATCH (u:User),(p:Prize),(ca:Category) CREATE (ch:Challenge {chid:'dassdshhhhasdasda',challenge_title:'Exm 2015', total_question_per_user:200,challenge_status:1,timestamp:'1471516538.4643',date:'2016-08-18'}), (p)-[:BELONG {rank:3}]->(ch),(ca)-[:BELONG {percentage_question:20}]->(ch) WHERE u.username = 'xyz@gmail.com' AND p.pid = 'e766d8cd-26d1-4848-ac97-15c233caa4d4' AND ca.catname = 'nature'"
```

I want to use `WHERE` clauses, without `WHERE` I run this query like this then its working

```
MATCH (u:User {username:'xyz@gmail.com'}),(p:Prize{pid:'e766d8cd-26d1-4848-ac97-15c233caa4d4'}),(ca:Category {catname:'nature'}) CREATE (ch:Challenge {chid:'dassdsdjgjasdasdasda',challenge_title:'Exm 2015', total_question_per_user:200,challenge_status:1,timestamp:'1471516538.4643',date:'2016-08-18'}), (p)-[:BELONG {rank:3}]->(ch),(ca)-[:BELONG {percentage_question:20}]->(ch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `WHERE` clause in the wrong spot.  The where clause needs to be used in conjunction with the `MATCH` statement and not the `CREATE`.

Something like this...

```
MATCH (u:User),(p:Prize),(ca:Category) 
WHERE u.username = 'xyz@gmail.com' 
AND p.pid = 'e766d8cd-26d1-4848-ac97-15c233caa4d4' 
AND ca.catname = 'nature'
CREATE (ch:Challenge {chid:'dassdshhhhasdasda', 
    challenge_title:'Exm 2015', 
    total_question_per_user:200, 
    challenge_status:1, 
    timestamp:'1471516538.4643', 
    date:'2016-08-18'})
   ,(p)-[:BELONG {rank:3}]->(ch)
   ,(ca)-[:BELONG {percentage_question:20}]->(ch)
```